# Why does gnu_pds not work even though I have installed gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, data-structures, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

I've recently installed gcc using Home-brew. Here are the details about my home-brew:

The command,  **'which gcc'** results to: /usr/bin/gcc

And the command **'brew info gcc'** results to: Required: gmp ✔, isl ✔, libmpc ✔, mpfr ✔

When ever I type in #include <ext/pb_ds ... it shows me a whole bunch of files I've never downloaded before which means that GCC and all of the files are actually downloaded.[image]

As you can see above,it clearly shows me the files.

Here is what it looks like in my finder:
[image]

However, I still recieve this error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 testprogram1.cpp -o testprogram1
testprogram1.cpp:2:9: fatal error: 'ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp' file not found
#include<ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
```

I'm not so sure why it is giving me this error even though I clearly have all of the files working.

Someone told me that when I typed **'which gcc'** it was meant to appear **/usr/local/bin/g++-9** and not **'/usr/bin/gcc**.

Maybe this could be the reason why but im not too sure how to fix(change) that. Thank you.

P.S: im using visual studio code and a mac. And these were the following steps when I installed HomeBrew:

**1. export HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1

2. brew update
3. brew upgrade
4. brew info gcc
5. brew install gcc
6. brew cleanup**

Comment: /usr/bing/gcc is indeed not gcc you have installed, and is not gcc at all, it's apple's clang compiler.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Oh, ok. How do I make g++-9 then? I downloaded homebrew so I dont understand why it's not gcc.

Comment: The easiest way, you just type /usr/local/bin/g++-9 instead of g++.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Where do I type this in? When I type '/usr/local/bin/g++-9' in the terminal I get 'zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/g++-9.' And when I type 'g++-9' alone in the terminal I get zsh: command not found: g++-9

Comment: I have no idea what version of gcc you installed and where homebrew put it. Perhaps `brew` can get you a list of files. Find one named g++ there.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. When I typed in 'brew' I didnt get a list of files. Instead I got this:Example usage:
  brew search [TEXT|/REGEX/]
  brew info [FORMULA...]
  brew install FORMULA...
  brew update
  brew upgrade [FORMULA...]
  brew uninstall FORMULA...
  brew list [FORMULA...]

Troubleshooting:
  brew config
  brew doctor
  brew install --verbose --debug FORMULA

Contributing:
  brew create [URL [--no-fetch]]
  brew edit [FORMULA...]

Further help:
  brew commands
  brew help [COMMAND]
  man brew
  https://docs.brew.sh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219587/discussion-between-rainier1-and-n-pronouns-m).

Comment: I'm sorry I have nothing to add, I don't have a mac and I don't use brew.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Oh ok, its ok